# What is wrong with this simple sql query? it returns 0 rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Newbie question, please forgive my ignorance :P

I have a datasets with different columns. Quizzes, names, grades. Some students have not done all quizzes. I just want people who did the 8 quizzes. I put this code:

```
SELECT *  FROM quiz_attempts 
WHERE qname like "onlinelernen_quiz_1" 
AND qname like "onlinelernen_quiz_2" 
AND qname like "onlinelernen_quiz_3" 
AND qname like "onlinelernen_quiz_4" 
AND qname like "onlinelernen_quiz_5" 
AND qname like "onlinelernen_quiz_6"
AND qname like "onlinelernen_quiz_7" 
AND qname like "onlinelernen_quiz_8"*/
```

Using `IN` or `OR` is working, but it shows any student who did quizzes. But i want **Only those students who did all 8 quizzes**.

Thanks for the Help.

Comment: Do you need only the students who did *all* 8 quizzes or the students who did *any* of the 8 quizzes?

Comment: SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  quiz_attempts 
WHERE qname LIKE "onlinelernen_quiz_%"

Comment: where is the name of column that contains student id?

Comment: It is not working, it shows any student, i want only who did the eight quizzes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query can't work since you are asking for all the records where qname is like "onlinelernen_quiz_1" and, **simultaneously**, like "onlinelernen_quiz_2", 3 ... , which is impossible.

Try this: It shows only the names of students whose name appears 8 times related to onlinelernen quizs

```
SELECT Q.stname
FROM quiz_attempts AS Q
WHERE Q.qname Like 'onlinelernen_quiz_%'
GROUP BY Q.stname
HAVING Count(Q.stname)=8;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Woah! There are already lots of answers, some of them being almost the same as this

Comment: Ok, Lian, you're wellcome!

Comment: i dont know, your one is the easiest!

Answer (score 2):

AND gives specific result when all condition matched. Use OR

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  quiz_attempts 
WHERE qname LIKE "onlinelernen_quiz_1" 
  OR qname LIKE "onlinelernen_quiz_2" 
  OR qname LIKE "onlinelernen_quiz_3" 
  OR qname LIKE "onlinelernen_quiz_4" 
  OR qname LIKE "onlinelernen_quiz_5" 
  OR qname LIKE "onlinelernen_quiz_6" 
  OR qname LIKE "onlinelernen_quiz_7" 
  OR qname LIKE "onlinelernen_quiz_8"
```

Comment: AHA!! so use OR for all the conditions!

Comment: Does this even need LIKE? You are searching for a specific search (no wildcards), so I would suggest use `=` over `LIKE`

Comment: Sorry, it is not working, cause i want students who did the eight quizzes. not any student who did a quiz

Comment: I though that OP wanted student who did all 8 quizzes. In your case its enough if he did any of the quizzes in which way its better to use "in" - dunno how u got 5+ to your answer when its obviously wrong one..

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible for one column, such as `qname` to take on multiple values in one row.  I assume that you mean `or` instead of `and`.  But, the better way to write this query is using `in`:

```
SELECT *
FROM quiz_attempts
WHERE qname in ('onlinelernen_quiz_1', 'onlinelernen_quiz_2', 
                'onlinelernen_quiz_3', 'onlinelernen_quiz_4', 
                'onlinelernen_quiz_5', 'onlinelernen_quiz_6', 
                'onlinelernen_quiz_7', 'onlinelernen_quiz_8'
               )
```

EDIT:

If you want students who took all 8 quizzes, then use aggregation:

```
SELECT studentid
FROM quiz_attempts
WHERE qname in ('onlinelernen_quiz_1', 'onlinelernen_quiz_2', 
                'onlinelernen_quiz_3', 'onlinelernen_quiz_4', 
                'onlinelernen_quiz_5', 'onlinelernen_quiz_6', 
                'onlinelernen_quiz_7', 'onlinelernen_quiz_8'
               )
GROUP BY studentid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT qname) = 8;
```

Comment: OP has tried using IN and says that he is getting the issue with that! Or did I miss something? `Using IN or OR is working, but it shows any student who did quizzes. *But i want who Only did the 8 quizzes.*`

Answer (score 2):

```
select studentID, count(*) as attempts
from quiz_attempts 
group by studentID
having  attempts=8
```

this returns students IDs assuming that you have a column that reserves student ID for each attempt.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are appending the quiz strings to same column each time when a student does next quiz.

If so then, try using this query,

```
SELECT *  FROM quiz_attempts 
WHERE qname like "%onlinelernen_quiz_1%" 
AND qname like "%onlinelernen_quiz_2%" 
AND qname like "%onlinelernen_quiz_3%" 
AND qname like "%onlinelernen_quiz_4%" 
AND qname like "%onlinelernen_quiz_5%" 
AND qname like "%onlinelernen_quiz_6%"
AND qname like "%onlinelernen_quiz_7%" 
AND qname like "%onlinelernen_quiz_8%"
```

Hope it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT Q.*
FROM   quiz_attempts
```

q
           INNER JOIN (SELECT 'onlinelernen_quiz_1' as qname UNION
                       SELECT 'onlinelernen_quiz_2'UNION
                       SELECT 'onlinelernen_quiz_3'UNION
                       SELECT 'onlinelernen_quiz_4'UNION
                       SELECT 'onlinelernen_quiz_5'UNION
                       SELECT 'onlinelernen_quiz_6'UNION
                       SELECT 'onlinelernen_quiz_7'UNION
                       SELECT 'onlinelernen_quiz_8') C
                   ON c.qname = q.qname

Comment: it gives me error, that C doesnt exist. i felt ur code should work but it shows an error

Answer (score 0):

If you have a PK on student-qname fields, you can count the rows grouped by student.
Something like this:

```
SELECT student_name,
       SUM(qname) AS total_quiz
FROM quiz_attempts
GROUP BY student_name
HAVING total_quiz = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

To catch the students who did *all* 8 quizzes it is tiresome but possible to do something like

```
SELECT * FROM quiz_attempts q1
WHERE qname like "onlinelernen_quiz_1"
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM quiz_attempts q2 
    WHERE qname like "onlinelernen_quiz_2"
) ON q1.student_id = q2.student_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM quiz_attempts q3 
    WHERE qname like "onlinelernen_quiz_3"
) ON q2.student_id = q3.student_id
```

and so on.

Comment: sorry i dont have a student id.. just name,quiz name and grade.